# How can I specify the latest commit version in Gradle

Tags: android, git, github, gradle

I'm using `Gradle` in my Android project,and I have added some dependencies in `build.gradle` file.For some reasons,I want to point to the latest commit for one of my dependencies.For example:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.0@aar'

}
```

I'm specifying `CircularReveal`'s version to be 1.1.0@aar,and I know currently it has fixed some bugs but have not released it yet.How can I specify a commit in Gradle?I know some basics about `Cocoapods`,and it can be done like this:

```
pod 'AFNetworking', :git => 'https://github.com/gowalla/AFNetworking.git', :commit => '082f8319af'
```

Can it be done in Gradle? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can not do this directly from Gradle, but there are Gradle plugins and tools you can use to achieve this.

You can do this using [Jitpack](https://jitpack.io/), an external tool. All you need to do is specify Jitpack as a repository:

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://jitpack.io"
    }
    // Define your other dependency repositories, if any
}
```

Then include your dependency:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:25aeca505d'
    // Include your other dependencies, if any
}
```

---

You can also use use the [gradle-git-repo-plugin](https://github.com/layerhq/gradle-git-repo-plugin) from Layer, but I haven't tried this one yet. An advantage(?) of this plugin is that it clones the repository on your local machine and adds it as a dependency from there.

Comment: hash include with jitpack never worked for me for some reason

Answer (score 2):

[Ugo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/779983/ugo) [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30565311/1266326) is probably the correct one, here's an alternative for some specific cases:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    compile 'com.github.ozodrukh:CircularReveal:1.1.+@aar' 
    // or 1.+ or even just +
}
```

That puts you on the latest version, no matter which one it is. Now, if you repository builds on a CI environment and deploys snapshots to Sonatype or a similar service, you can do

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "https://project.sonatype.io"
    }
}
```

And along with the other change you'll end up in the -SNAPSHOT versions. This behaviour reports warnings on build because your builds will not be reproducible, but that's a given if you're targeting CI versions.